# Netbeans platform vs. Visual Studio Extensibility

Tags: visual-studio-2008, netbeans, extensibility, netbeans-plugins

it could be that the word versus is too strong for my question but anyway here we go. I have used the Netbeans platform in the past and I was really impressed with it. I haven't tried anything however in VS (2008 my current edition). Does anyone have experience with VS on extensibility? Is it as powerful as Netbeans and can I build custom UIs and code editors in it? We are porting a big project from java to c# and we are interested in building a number of editors with grids and project management within VS. Your views would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be equally (possibly more) impressed with VS, particularly the 2010. edition.